# "if $f:R \to R $ is $\mathbb{A}$ -measurable then for all $\delta>0$ exist $a \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $(f^{-1}(a,a+\delta))^c $ is countable "

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Take $X \neq \emptyset$. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the following  $\sigma-$algebra:
$$\mathbb{A}=\{ A \in P(X) : A \text{  is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable}  \}$$

I want to know if it's true or false:

"if $f:R \to R $ is $\mathbb{A}$ -measurable then for all $\delta>0$ exist $a \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $(f^{-1}(a,a+\delta))^c $ is countable "

My suspicion is that it is false, I tried to do it as absurd, but I did not get anything.

Comment: Pre-image of any set will have at most one element? $f:R \to R$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Pre-image is $R$ or $\emptyset$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f$ is $\mathbb A$-measurable, either $f^{-1}(a, a + \delta)$ or $(f^{-1}(a, a + \delta))^c$ is countable. As $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup\limits_{n={-\infty}}^\infty (\frac{n\delta}{2}, \frac{n\delta}{2} + 1)$, we have $\mathbb{R} = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{n={-\infty}}^\infty (\frac{n\delta}{2}, \frac{n\delta}{2} + \delta)) = \bigcup\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty f^{-1}(\frac{n\delta}{2}, \frac{n\delta}{2} + \delta)$

As $\mathbb R$ is uncountable and union at the right side is countable, at least one of terms (corresponding to say $m$) is uncountable - thus for $a = \frac{n\delta}{2}$,  $f^{-1}(a, a + \delta)$ is uncountable and $(f^{-1}(a, a + \delta))^c$ is countable.